# Object height defined by page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have this code:

html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="column"></div>
</div>
```

and Css

```
#wrap {
    display: block;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 400px
}
#column {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px
}
```

And I want to change #column height when scrolling page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how exactly you want to change the height of `#column` but here is the example:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  // scrollTop() = vertical position of the scroll bar
  $("#column").css("height", $(document).scrollTop() + 20);
});
```

Fiddle is **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/s5NQp/)**.

Comment: It would be that but it doesn't work. #column height immediately back to default height

My bad. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use resize event.

```
    $(window).resize(function() {  $('#column').css("height","??px"); });
```